# toContainHtml() vs. toHaveHtml() in jasmine-jquery

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

In the [jquery-jasmine documentation](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/blob/c5fda66b6841da716ffdaf07d8f01da1d61ce97c/README.md) (I've listed the exact revision of the docs in case they change).

It describes:

toContainHtml(string)

```
expect($('<div><ul></ul><h1>header</h1></div>')).toContainHtml('<ul></ul>')
```

toHaveHtml(string)

```
expect($('<div><span></span></div>')).toHaveHtml('<span></span>')
```

When should I use toContainHtml() and when should I use toHaveHtml()? From the examples I can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by this [ticket on jasmine-jquery's github page](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/issues/76)

toHaveHtml() is more exacting using a `==` check

Whereas toContainHtml() uses an `indexOf()` check.

However the example in the documentation doesn't really demonstrate this, so I'm still not certain.